# Event setOnItemClickListener doesn't work in my list

Tags: android

I call the event `OnItemClickListener` in my list `lista`, but it doesn't work, the `Toast` not is shown.

below my code `fragment1.java`

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    Switch mySwitch;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){      
        //nome dos reles
        String[] atividades = new String[]{"lampada","tomada quarto","tomada cozinha","geladeira"};

        //interface
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_acionamento, container,false);       

        //lista
        ListView lista = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mylistView);          

        //botão acionar
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAcionar);

        //adaptador de string para reles
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.modelo_lista_reles,atividades);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        //evento do botão acionar
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CUBANAJARRA", getId()).show();
            }
        });

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CUBANAJARRA_lista", getId()).show();
            }
        });

        return(view);
    }
}
```

My code for `modelo_lista_rele.xml`(I use this for create a list with switch):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

my code for `layout_acionamento.xml`(used for view that I return in fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAcionar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAcionar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Acionar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have buttons or clickable views within you item layouts?

Comment: Thanks. I answered below.

Comment: I wanted when it was clicked on the switch in the list item, the event was called ItemClickListener

Comment: Your switch will consume the event, so you can't get OnItemClickListener to fire. You can use `Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener` to get the check change listener to fire.

Comment: But my Switch is created in run time, how I can set events?

Comment: Were you able to get the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap you `Switch` around with a `LinearLayout`, and make sure that you either block descendantFocusability or set the Switch's xml params focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false. This should get things working. What's happening is that the Switch is consuming the touch event so the ListView never has a chance to fire the OnItemClickListener.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**: Based on comment: Take a look at this [YouTube video by Romain Guy on ListViews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). It should give you a good idea of what's going on below.

Create a `ViewHolder` class to keep track of individual widgets in your item layout:

```
public static class ViewHolder{
  public Switch mSwitch;
}
```

Then, in your adapter, override getView. The code below may look weird at first, but it's the proper way to get the benefits of recycling views so your list scrolls fast.

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.modelo_lista_rele.xml, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                holder.switch = convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            String item = getItem(position);

            //Do something with item here
            //holder.mSwitch.setText(item);
            //holder.mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I can't do this, because if I involve my `Switch` in LinearLayout I get this error: “ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView.”

Comment: You can do it. You would just need to override ArrayAdapter.getView. I'll update my answer to include how to override getView.

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CUBANAJARRA", getId()).show();
```

The third parameter is length not id.
Try to use `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` or `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` instead like:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CUBANAJARRA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: The error occurs in event OnItemClickListener, where nothing works.
Likely, it isn't called.